# Disable element scrolling with keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xo85L9f/)

So I'm trying to disable scrolling of a div when another div is visible.

The code bellow I'm using does just that, but only when using mousewheel to scroll.

If I click the scrollbar and drag it, or if I focus the div and use keyboard down button, the scrolling still happens.

Why is that and how can I solve my problem (possibly without overlaying a transparent element over my scrollbar or similar "hacks")?

```
$('#element').on('scroll mousewheel keydown keypress keyup', function (event) {
    const element = $(event.currentTarget);
    const shouldScroll = false;

    if (!shouldScroll) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;   
    }
});
```

Comment: You can detect the keycode of the arrow keys and stop the event. They are keycode 37, 38, 39 and 40. Don't forget pageUp, pageDown, home and end keys though. Frankly this sounds a lot more work than it's worth - almost to the point of being an XY question. There's not much you can do to stop the scrolling on drag, though. Not without ruining mouse functionality, anyway.

Comment: What about adding `overflow: hidden;` in the style of the desired div ?

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` would hide the scroll altogether, which I do not want.

Comment: I did try to stop all key events (as you can see in the fiddle) and key scrolling still works.

Comment: If you don't want to disable all scrolling, when specifically do you want to allow it?

Comment: It's always allowed, except when the `shouldScroll` boolean is set to false, which happens outside of scope of this event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this?

```js
var scrollEnabled = true;
var scrollX = 0;
var scrollY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div.outer').on('scroll', function(event) {
    if (!scrollEnabled) this.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
  });
  
  $('#tglBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    if (scrollEnabled == true) {
      scrollEnabled = false;
      scrollX = $('div.outer').scrollLeft();
      scrollY = $('div.outer').scrollTop();
    } else {
      scrollEnabled = true;
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
div.outer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

div.inner:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="tglBtn" value="Enable/Disable scrolling" />
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't do it like this, since the div could have had it's scroll set to something other than (0, 0) the instance `shouldScroll` bool is set to false.

I could try saving scroll positions before the scroll is disabled, so this could work with some modification.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, yes. Still seems a bit 'hacky' to be honest, but it will have to do, for now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Such things are always 'hacky'... Thank you for accepting the answer!